# yo ionic doesn't work on command promopt

Tags: ionic-framework

i am new for ionic, and follow the https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic to do my first ionic and angularjs mobile app.I've installed generator-ionic and created a directory named my-ionic-project and the try to run yo ionic, but the command prompt me that yo is either internal or external command
[image]

Comment: For the future, please don't post image. People who have the same error cannot search for it.

Answer (score 0):

To use `yo` command you have to install `yeoman`.

```
 npm install -g yeoman
```

But to start, I advise you to use ionic started template.

With

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

More infos here : http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/